# Update viewport after toggle of cycles shadows for all objects

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shadows, visibility

I wrote this little script to toggle the visibility of the shadows of all objects.

It works quite well, but at the end of the script, I'd like to update the viewport. I tried the "hack" with the redraw_timer, but actually I don't want to use it, because it's not recommended and mainly because it doesn't work with the blender version 2.78c. ;-)

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    try:
        ob.cycles_visibility.shadow ^= 1
    except:
        print ("No shadows: ", ob.name)

# Did not work:        
# bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)

bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens["Scripting"]
bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens["Default"]
```

So I just switched to another screen layout and back to default.

That works. However, I guess there are more elegant ways to do this.

Thanks brockmann, thanks @all
Here's the updated and tested version:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    try:
        ob.cycles_visibility.shadow ^= 1
    except:
        print ("No shadows: ", ob.name)

bpy.context.scene.update_tag()
```

Comment: I think `bpy.context.scene.update_tag()` is the right way to do it.

Comment: ^= 1 actually toggles?  That's something new I've just learned for Python.

Comment: @TeaCrab - Technically it is a bitwise [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). Python uses `^` as a shortcut to it's [`xor()`](https://docs.python.org/3//library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) function.

Comment: As @brockmann suggests you should be able to use [`ob.update_tag()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.update_tag) in the loop and finish with [`scene.update()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.update) but I don't see a refresh. I have used `scene.frame_set(scene.frame_current)` to force a refresh.

Comment: @sambler   Thanks for the explanation. :D

Comment: @brockmann Hi, please I have deleted by mistake (Accepting a duplicate) your suggestion to my [question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183442/collection-of-blend-files). Could you please give it to me again ? I've found no other way to contact you.

Comment: not working for me after changing the world light map resolution using:
```bpy.data.scenes[scene_name].world.cycles.sample_map_resolution = 4096```